# Changing the position of a button depending on the slide that is currently shown in a slideshow

Tags: html, css, image, button, position

There is a slideshow on my webpage. Within this slideshow, I have added a button. I want this button to only show up on slide 1. I want a different button at a different position and size to show up on slide 2. However, the button shows up on all slides. How can I cause the button to only show up on one slide?

I have tried to create seperate id's for each button tag on my HTML document, and then create seperate styling for each button. However, all of the buttons are shown all of the time, regardless of which slide I am on.

For example, the first slide should look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UB9D.png)
The second slide should look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR0Gu.png)

I have used this HTML code:

```html
<div class="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="images/banner-1.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="images/banner-2.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="images/banner-3.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="images/banner-4.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="images/banner-5.jpeg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="button">Shop Now</button>
</div>
```

I have used this CSS code:

```css
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 .swiper {
     width: 100%;
     height: fit-content;
     position: absolute;
}
 .swiper-slide img {
     width: 100%;
}
 #button {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
     top: 350px;
     left: 850px;
     font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the button within the first `swiper-slide`, set some `id` to the first `swiper-slide`, and CSS would be `#yourID {possition:relative;} .button{possition:absolute;}`
Follow by more styling, but this will make your button be fixed only within the first slide. Just make sure you set the styling to ID of your first slide and button, to avoid some trouble in the future.